# How to call a function from a string?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, callback, scope, eval

How would you call a function from a string, possibly including a scope, and without using `eval`.

The idea is that I want to specify a callback inside an a `dragEndCallback` attribute, and call it giving the drag start and end objects as parameters. Some kind of generic drag and drop in my case.

Most people will tell you to use eval, but it's unsafe, slow, and a really bad idea overall.

Here are some sample strings that I would like to support:

```
"NamespaceA.functionName"
"functionName"
"NamespaceB.NamespaceA.functionName"
"ClassB.methodName"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic, clean, and convenient way to do it. It returns undefined if the function was not found.

```
window.getFunctionFromString = function(string)
{
    var scope = window;
    var scopeSplit = string.split('.');
    for (i = 0; i < scopeSplit.length - 1; i++)
    {
        scope = scope[scopeSplit[i]];

        if (scope == undefined) return;
    }

    return scope[scopeSplit[scopeSplit.length - 1]];
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to return the object it is a property of as well. Calling `NamespaceA.functionName()` can be totally different than just `functionName()`.

Comment: A few other points worth mentioning is that it uses objects, strictly speaking; not scopes. You cannot refer to a scope as a variable. Moreover, this does not support properties containing a dot.

Answer (score 0):

If by "scope" you mean what scope to bring into the function, something like this could work:

```
var callFn = function(str, scope) {

    scope = scope || window;

    var namespaces = str.split('.'),
        fn = window; // or whatever root you want

    while(fn = fn[namespaces.shift()]){
        if(typeof fn == 'function') {
            fn.call(scope);
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

Example:

```
window.ns = {
    one: {
        two: function(){ console.log('Two!') }
    }
};
window.foo = function() {
    console.log(this); // document
};

callFn('ns.one.two');
callFn('foo', document);
```